# Inequality of $\vert \text{tanh}(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{3}\vert\leq\frac{1}{8}$ for $x\in[-1/4,1/4]$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions

I have an assignment, that I cannot seem to find a starting point for. I am not looking for the specific answer, but only where to begin. Any pointers are appreciated.

I have to prove the inequality
$\vert \tanh(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{3}\vert\leq\frac{1}{8}$ for $x\in[-1/4,1/4]$
where $x-\frac{x^3}{3}$ is the 3rd order Taylor expansion.

I've tried with the triangle inequalities, Lagrange remainders, and a lot of other stuff, but I am no where near a correct argumentation. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Taylor formula with Lagrange remainder sounds good. What did you get, and what is missing?

Comment: I tried to prove the inequality would be less than the 4th order expansion, but I cannot obtain the 1/8. Do you know it works for remainders? Then I'll just continue on that path...

Answer (score 2):

Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder gives
$$
\tanh(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{3} = \frac{\tanh^{(4)}(\xi)}{4!} x^4
$$
for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$.

For an estimate of $\tanh^{(4)}(\xi)$  use that

- $\tanh'(x) = 1 - \tanh(x)^2 $, this allows to express $\tanh^{(4)}(x)$ as a polynomial in $\tanh(x)$ with constant coefficients.
- $|\tanh(x)| < 1$ for $x \in \Bbb R$.

This gives
$$
 \tanh^{(4)}(x) = 16 \tanh(x) - 40 \tanh^3(x) + 24 \tanh^5(x)
$$
and therefore
$$
 \left| \tanh(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{3} \right| \le \frac{80}{4!} \left( \frac 1 4 \right)^4 = \frac{5}{384}
$$
for $|x| \le 1/4$.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but this is kind of where I lost track; how can I assure my polynomial is less than 1/8 for $x\in[-1/4,1/4]$? I feel like I am missing something super simple. Is there some theorem I have forgotten?

Comment: @RRexHansen: What did you get for the polynomial? And note that you also have the  $\frac{x^4}{4!}$ factor, which is less than $\frac{1}{24 \cdot 4^4}$ in absolute value.

Comment: I get $\tanh''''(x)=-2-2\tanh(x)+2\tanh^2(x)+2\tanh^3(x)+\tanh^4(x)+\tanh^5(x)$, but how do i prove this is less than 1/8?

Comment: @RRexHansen: I get $\tanh^{(4)}(x) = 16 \tanh(x) - 40 \tanh^3(x) + 24 \tanh^5(x)$. It follows that $|\tanh^{(4)}(\xi)| < 16 + 40 + 24 = 80$. That is a very rough estimate, but good enough for this purpose.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I'll go back and correct my mistakes.

Comment: Hello @Martin R . How did the prove go as I am only seeing that the expression is less than 80 from your comment but we have to prove it less that or equal to 1/8

Comment: @mathstudent23: I have added the details. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: @MartinR The polynomial of the taylor itself is wrong, right? I.e should be a minus and not a plus between the $x$ and $1/3 x^3$. As it is the expansion at $a=0$ of degree 3 for $\tanh{x]$

Comment: @mathstudent23: The Taylor polynomial  is $x - x^3/3$. The remainder is $\tanh(x) - (x-x^3/3) = \tanh(x) - x + x^3/3$.

Comment: @MartinR Ty makes sense now!

Comment: @MartinR The only thing is how you made the polynomial of the hyperbolic tangent.

Comment: @mathstudent23: You use the relation $\tanh'(x) = 1 - \tanh(x)^2$ repeatedly. With $f = \tanh$ you have $f' = 1-f^2$. Differentiate that and you get $f'' = -2ff' = -2f(1-f^2) = -2f+2f^3$, and so on.